# Blob to Varchar Conversion Issue

Tags: sql, oracle11g, blob

I have the following select statement.

```
SELECT REPLACE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(GDTXFT,2000,1)),CHR(0),'') as GDTXFT
from f00165;
```

It is resulting in the following error message.

> Error code: 29275, Error message: ORA-29275: partial multibyte character.

GDTXFT is defined with `BLOB` datatype.

From looking around, I understand that the `substr` function is cutting the byte into half which is causing issue in the conversion of byte into character. Is there any way to get rid of the error?

All I am trying to do is convert the BLOB column into Varchar column. But I could not find any other way to do it so far. Is there any other way to attain this? Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Any particular reason that the database column type is a BLOB instead of a CLOB?

Comment: You need to first convert the complete BLOB to a CLOB, then you can extract the substring, e.g. using [this](https://oracle-base.com/dba/script?category=miscellaneous&file=blob_to_clob.sql)

Answer (score 0):

The way that I approached your same issue is to pull the data from DB2 in HEX but turn it into VARCHAR. The result dataset is stored in a MSSQL staged table as a VARCHAR column. The final step is to read this VARCHAR column that has HEX values and turn them into ASCII characters. All the above steps were performed using SSIS.
These are the two MS SQL tables that were used. The first table F00165_stage is to store the data from DB2. The comments column stores the HEX data as VARCHAR. The second final table is to store the HEX data turned into ASCII characters.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[F00165_stage](
[SDKCOO] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
[SDDOCO] [int] NULL,
[SDDCTO] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
[SDLNID] [int] NULL,
[comments] [nvarchar](500) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[final_table](
[SDKCOO] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
[SDDOCO] [int] NULL,
[SDDCTO] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
[SDLNID] [int] NULL,
[comments] [nvarchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here are the scripts that make this work. I am retrieving the sales comments (F4211) that are stored in F00165.
The first step is to retrieve the data from JDE. The keys to link to your F00165 might be stored differently, so make the necessary changes, if needed.

```
SELECT sd.sdkcoo 
,sd.sddoco 
,sd.sddcto 
,sd.sdlnid 
,CAST(HEX(gd.gdtxft) AS VARCHAR(500)) comments
FROM F4211 sd
LEFT JOIN F00165 gd ON gd.gdobnm='GT4211A' AND gd.gdtxky=sd.sddoco || '|' || sd.sddcto || '|' || sd.sdkcoo || '|' || CAST((sd.sdlnid / 1000)  AS NUMERIC(8,3))
WHERE 1=1
AND CAST(HEX(gd.gdtxft) AS VARCHAR(500)) IS NOT NULL
```

The second step is to insert the JDE records in the final table.

```
INSERT INTO final_table
SELECT sdkcoo,sddcto,sddoco,sdlnid,'' AS comments
FROM F4211_stage
```

The last step is to perform the update for the HEX (comments) column. This will turn the HEX values into ASCII characters.

```
UPDATE ft SET ft.comments=SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), REPLACE(st.comments,'00',''), 2)),1,100)
FROM final_table ft
JOIN F4211_stage st ON st.sdkcoo=ft.sdkcoo AND st.sddoco=ft.sddoco AND st.sddcto=ft.sddcto AND st.sdlnid=ft.sdlnid
```